# Calling different classes in Libgdx Android

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I need help calling different classes.
I want to create a class for, a menu, the game, an option menu, credits etc.
 I just need to know how to call a different class

//Ok i have edited my post, hope i provided enough information.

game class

```js
//Add Screens
    private MenuScreen menuScreen;
    public final static int MENU=0;

public void changeScreens(int screen){
    switch(screen){
        case MENU:
            if(menuScreen==null){
                menuScreen=new MenuScreen(this);
            }
    }
}

//Render (When you click on the button)

if(drawplay) {

             menuScreen=new MenuScreen(this);
             setScreen( menuScreen);
             
             
//MenuScreen Class

ublic class MenuScreen implements Screen {
    private rugby parent;

    public MenuScreen(rugby rugby){
     parent = rugby;

    }
    
    
    @Override
    public void render(float delta) {
    Gdx.app.log( "Play","Play" );
    }
```

Comment: Your question has issues. (1) the question is very general (2) the code snippet is incomplete.  Sounds like you need to learn more about java in general before asking a question.

Comment: Well if you help, i will learn more and more. Ive only published the incomplete parts as i dont know how to call the class or render. Will you help me or not ?

Comment: There are plenty of tutorials online for making games with the items you mentioned such as http://www.gamefromscratch.com/page/LibGDX-Tutorial-series.aspx and https://www.gamedevelopment.blog/full-libgdx-game-tutorial-flgt-home/ You should learn from those and only ask questions for specific problems here on so.

Comment: You might want to start with a Java tutorial, though. Calling/creating classes  has nothing to do with Android or LibGDX

Comment: Also, we can't see the definition of `public class Menu` to know what object it is, or what `render()` method you have overridden. Therefore, it's hard to answer with these out-of-context code blocks. Please [edit] your question to show a [mcve]